# jQuery > Update inline script on form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the [ChemDoodle Web Components](http://web.chemdoodle.com/components.php) to display molecules on a web page. Basically, I can just insert the following script in my page and it will create an HTML5 canvas element to display the molecule.

```
<script>
    var transform1 = new TransformCanvas('transform1', 200, 200, true);
    transform1.specs.bonds_useJMOLColors = true;
    transform1.specs.bonds_width_2D = 3;
    transform1.specs.atoms_useJMOLColors = true;
    transform1.specs.atoms_circles_2D = true;
    transform1.specs.backgroundColor = 'black';
    transform1.specs.bonds_clearOverlaps_2D = true;
    transform1.loadMolecule(readPDB(molecule));
</script>
```

In this example, "molecule" is a variable that I have defined in an external script by using the jQuery.ajax() function to load a PDB file. This is all fine and good.

Now, I would like to include a form on the page that will allow a user to paste in a PDB molecule definition. Upon submitting the form, I want to update the "molecule" variable with the form data so that the ChemDoodle Web Components script will work its magic and display molecule defined by the PDB definition pasted into the form.

I am using the following jQuery code to process the the form submission.

```
$(".button").click(function() {  
 // validate and process form here

    //hide previous errors
    $('.error').hide();

    //validate pdb textarea field
    var pdb = $("textarea#pdb").val();
    if (pdb == "") {
        $("label#pdb_error").show();
        $("textarea#pdb").focus();
        return false;
    }
    molecule = pdb;

});
```

This code is setting the "molecule" variable upon the form submission but it is not being passed back to the inline script as I had hoped. I have tried a number of variations on this but can't seem to get it right. Any clues as to where I might be going wrong would be much appreciated.

Comment: Irrelevant to your question, but you can optimize your jQuery selectors which are selecting by ID (`#`), by removing the node type from the selector (e.g just `$("#pdb")`). ID's should be unique on the page, so there is no need to limit the results. For selections via class (`.something`) and attribute (`[name=something]`), it is optimal to specify node types.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe make your inline script a function?

```
<script>
function LoadMolecule(molecule) {
    var transform1 = new TransformCanvas('transform1', 200, 200, true);
    transform1.specs.bonds_useJMOLColors = true;
    //...etc...
    transform1.specs.bonds_clearOverlaps_2D = true;
    transform1.loadMolecule(readPDB(molecule));
}
</script>
```

Then...

```
$(".button").click(function() {  
 // validate and process form here

    //hide previous errors
    $('.error').hide();

    //validate pdb textarea field
    var pdb = $("textarea#pdb").val();
    if (pdb == "") {
        $("label#pdb_error").show();
        $("textarea#pdb").focus();
        return false;
    }
    LoadMolecule(pdb);    
});
```

Comment: Matt, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, when I tried this this method, the canvas appeared for a split second and then disappeared. I think this is probably something to do with how the ChemDoodle script generates the canvas. I may just need to step back and reconsider my goal here, given my limited scripting abilities.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: I think I massively mis-understood the question. I was thinking you had a textbox of JavaScript code, that you needed to be parsed as JavaScript to form one of your molocules :). On the off-chance I did read the question right, I'll leave this answer here.... :)**

You'll have to use dirty [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/eval), but be aware of the [implications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/eval)

```
try { 
  eval(pdb);
} catch (e) {
  // error; syntax error in their code.
};
```

Setting `molecule = pdb` doesn't really make sense. `eval` returns the value returned by the last expression (e.g. whatever `loadMolecule` returns in your example).

The reason it doesn't work at the moment is because `pdb` is simply string (JavaScript doesn't care if it contains valid JavaScript or not; it's just a string!)

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you're using a form. If it's a real one, do you need to block the page submission? If so, I think you need a `return false` somewhere along the successful path to prevent the form from actually submitting.

Comment: Doh! That was what I was missing (in combination with Matt Shermans's input). Thanks!