# Updating a <script> element on form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe for payment processing, which uses an inline `<script></script>` within a `<form>` element, like so:

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="payButton" style="display:none;">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="myprivatekeygoeshere"
    data-amount="4900"
    data-name="Sample Name"
    data-description="We use Stripe for 100% secure payment processing."
    data-image="/agm-128-128.png"
    data-email="THIS IS WHAT I'D LIKE TO CHANGE"
  </script>
</form>
```

This form is step 2 of a two-part validation. The first gets a user's info, like name, email address, location and saves it to my server. Once this happens, this Stripe form is opened.

Inside the script, there's an option for `data-email`. This auto-fills a user's email address and I'd like to update this based on a user's input in `step 1` of the form.

Using Javascript or jQuery, is it possible to achieve this?

Something along the lines of:

```
$('#form1').submit(function(){
  var email = $('#form1 #email').val();
  $('#payButton script').attr('data-email', email);
});
```

Possible duplicate of this question which didn't have a proper resolution and is 3 yeas old: [jQuery > Update inline script on form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026304/jquery-update-inline-script-on-form-submission)

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible to modify the form after submission but before resolution? If so, the answer is yes you can, just use preventDefault() inside a submit() event handler from jQuery.

Comment: No, I'm asking to update the `data-email` attribute of the inline `<script>` tag that sits within form #2, after submitting form #1.

Comment: Does the code you posted do what you want? If not, what would you like it to do differently?

Comment: @probackpacker Well this is embarrassing. In an attempt to give a quick idea of what I wanted to do I posted some code which I was certain wouldn't work - but it actually worked! I was sure you couldn't target `<script>` tags with jQuery but I guess I was wrong. Cheers for the probing question which proved I'm better at jQuery than I give myself credit for!

Answer (score 1):

The answer was, hilariously/stupidly, in the question - thanks to @probackpacker, who got me to test the dummy code that I posted as an example of what wouldn't work. It actually did work:

```
$('#form1').submit(function(){
  var email = $('#form1 #email').val();
  $('#payButton script').attr('data-email', email);
});
```

This correctly targets the `<script>` tag and lets you change the attributes.